# Understanding the Maven Build Process

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee

I have a project that I am working on for school that is using hibernate for the jpa implementation. My question is, if inside of the hibernate properties file I turn off the schema generation, and I want to update the schema manually (my ddl file) and have my schema be deployed with the application, what do I need to include in my `<build></build>` tag to have the schema as part of what gets deployed?

Under src/main/resources I have a ddl directory that contains the table creation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [sql-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/examples/execute.html) to execute sql during build process

something like

```
<build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>

        <dependencies>
          <!-- specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>8.1-407.jdbc3</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <!-- common configuration shared by all executions -->
        <configuration>
          <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
          <url>jdbc:postgressql://localhost:5432:yourdb</url>
          <username>postgres</username>
          <password>password</password>
          <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and
               have maven to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey}
          -->
          <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
          <!--all executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true-->
          <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>create-data</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
              <fileset>
                <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                <includes>
                  <include>src/test/sql/test-data2.sql</include>
                </includes>
              </fileset>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

      </plugin>
      [...]
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
```

change configuration based on your DB

Comment: the build happens on my development machine, but the app is actually being deployed to a server somewhere else, so how does that work?

Comment: production database deployment should be independent of build process, it should be tied to app bootstrap, this is more suitable for test db creation for test execution, if you still want to do it just change the database url and other configuration and it will point to the remote machine